# Solve CPLEX .mod with Java

Tags: java, cplex

I have written a model and the corresponding data with CPLEX (.mod & .dat file). Is it possible to call these files with Java and solve them?

Answer (score 2):

yes and you have many examples in CPLEX_Studio129\opl\examples\opl_interfaces\java

in mulprod.cs you will read

```
IloOplFactory.setDebugMode(true);
        IloOplFactory oplF = new IloOplFactory();
        IloOplErrorHandler errHandler = oplF.createOplErrorHandler();
        IloOplModelSource modelSource = oplF.createOplModelSource(DATADIR
                + "/mulprod.mod");
        IloOplSettings settings = oplF.createOplSettings(errHandler);
        IloOplModelDefinition def = oplF.createOplModelDefinition(modelSource,settings);
        IloCplex cplex = oplF.createCplex();
        cplex.setOut(null);
        IloOplModel opl = oplF.createOplModel(def, cplex);
        IloOplDataSource dataSource = oplF.createOplDataSource(DATADIR
                + "/mulprod.dat");
        opl.addDataSource(dataSource);
        opl.generate();
        if (cplex.solve())
        {
            System.out.println("OBJECTIVE: " + opl.getCplex().getObjValue());
            opl.postProcess();
            opl.printSolution(System.out);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No solution!");
        }
```